# App crashes after calling Firebase Firestore object.collection | cannot add firebase firestore collection

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My code create a new user in my firebase database, means the createUserWithEmailAndPassword method is working but after that app is crashing.

Reference: My code was working at first but after doing some changes in my firebase app project service account , code is not working.

```
 mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(shopEmail,shopPassword)
    .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                ShopObject newShop = new ShopObject(shopName,shopKeeper,shopLocation,shopEmail,shopPhone,placeAddress,placeLat,placeLon);
                db.collection("shops")
                        .add(newShop)
                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),documentReference.getId(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        })
                        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Registration Object Fail",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        });
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Registration Sucess",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Registration Fail",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

My Gradle File

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:15.0.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Did you inspect logcat for the stacktrace? Where is it crashing exactly? What's the error message?

Comment: You app is crashing giving what error?

Comment: I have fixed my error. Thanks for answering

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to be fine. Though you are not sharing the logcat error message try the following suggestions to solve the problem.

1. Ensure that the firebase rules are set correctly according to your project.
2. Ensure that you do not have nullPointer exceptions in your code like trying to get a reference to a FirebaseAuth without initializing the FirebaseDatabase instance.
3. since you are using cloud firestore ensure that in your firebase console you chose cloud firestore as your database

Comment: I have fixed it. Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are adding "ShopObject newShop" object to the firebase.

```
ShopObject newShop = new ShopObject(shopName,shopKeeper,shopLocation,shopEmail,shopPhone,placeAddress,placeLat,placeLon);
                db.collection("shops")
                        .add(newShop)
```

This is not the supported data-type by firebase.
You must put it in any of the [supported data type](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types)  like HashMap and then add.